# Allow only One checkbox per group OR! have radio fire an UNcheck event

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, show-hide, checkboxlist

I have a form that has many sets of questions, and depending on the answer or answers, more fields will populate (or unpopulate) via classes (display:none and display:visible).

The checkboxes work perfectly to hide and unhide their sections, but my problem is that I need only ONE checkbox per group to be checked, otherwise it gets wonky.

[See this fiddle for my checkbox example.](https://jsfiddle.net/illymjay/9zhLrk30/1/)

*"Why not use radios, they serve that purpose perfectly!"*
I would LOVE to use radios! However, when they un-check each other, they do it silently and I can't seem to capture an event to help toggle *off* the visibility of its span.

[See THIS fiddle for my radios example.](https://jsfiddle.net/illymjay/dob2L9nx/204/)

Also, I am using pure vanilla javascript. Most solutions I've come across deal with only one group of inputs, where as I'm using a naming convention to allow the code to work for multiple groups of inputs. I have searched and trailed and errored but can't seem to find a solution that works.. I thank you in advance for any and all help!

```
// 1. find all radios and add EventListener triggering showHide(), passing the radio ID as the argument
radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
radios.forEach(radioInput => addListener(radioInput));

function addListener(radioInput) {
  radioInput.setAttribute("onClick", `showHide(${radioInput.id})`);
}

// 2. showHide() function //
function showHide(radID) {
  // if radio is a trigger, ready its matching SPAN id (#groupname_toggle)
  if (radID.className === 'trigger') {
    var spanID = radID.name + '_toggle';
    // if trigger is checked, show the span
    if (radID.checked) {
      document.getElementById(spanID).setAttribute('class', 'toggle-visible');
    }
    // if trigger is UNchecked, hide the span
    else {
      document.getElementById(spanID).setAttribute('class', 'toggle-hidden');
    }
  // if its not a trigger, do nothing. 
  } else {
    console.log("It doesn't trigger anything.");
  }
}
```

The questions on the example are just for example's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out, and it ended up being a lot less verbose than my other attempts! I tested this out on both radios and checkboxes, works perfectly! I just need to make sure it works across as many browsers as possible.

```
// find all checkboxes and add EventListener triggering showHide(), passing the checkbox ID as the argument
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (const cbInput of checkboxes) {
        cbInput.setAttribute("onChange", `showHide(${cbInput.id})`);
    }

function showHide(cbID) {
    // Get only the inputs that share the name of the clicked input
    var cbGroup = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+cbID.name+"']");
    // Deselect other inputs in the group
        for (const cbInput of cbGroup) {
            if (cbInput.id !== cbID.id) {
                cbInput.checked = false;
            }
        }
    
    var spanID = cbID.name + '_toggle';
    // If current input is a trigger, show span if checked, hide if unchecked
    if (cbID.className === 'trigger') {
        if (cbID.checked) { spanShow(spanID); } 
        else { spanHide(spanID); }
    }
    // if current input is not a trigger, hide the span
    else {spanHide(spanID);}
}

function spanShow(spanID) {
    document.getElementById(spanID).classList.add('toggle-visible');
    document.getElementById(spanID).classList.remove('toggle-hidden');
}
function spanHide(spanID) {
    document.getElementById(spanID).classList.add('toggle-hidden');
    document.getElementById(spanID).classList.remove('toggle-visible');
}
```

**For radios** - (as checkboxes naturally do) with this method, the unselected radio now has an actual status of checked = false (as opposed to silently being not "checked").

**For checkboxes** - to make only one checkbox of a group selectable (as radios naturally do), I needed to set all checkboxes of that group name (whose ID was not the same as the clicked one) to status:checked = false.

**For both** - A mistake I made was leaving all the work to the inputs that had class="trigger". Now, the inputs that aren't triggers will always hide the span, since their values don't require more information.